# save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit' Django Error

Tags: python, django

im geting this error "save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'"
what im trying to do is request user when user upload his files.

update i added my model.py and forms.py and also screen shot of error sorry my fisrt time learning python/django.

[screen shot](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/849/NMEc3J.png)

model.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    input_file  = models.FileField(max_length=255, upload_to='uploads', storage=fs)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.input_file.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('upload-delete', )
```

forms.py

```
class BaseForm(FileFormMixin, django_bootstrap3_form.BootstrapForm):
    title = django_bootstrap3_form.CharField()



class MultipleFileExampleForm(BaseForm):
    input_file = MultipleUploadedFileField()

    def save(self):
        for f in self.cleaned_data['input_file']:
            Document.objects.create(
                input_file=f
            )
```

here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MultipleFileExampleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = form.save(commit=False)
            newdoc.user = request.user
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myfiles.views.list'))
    else:
        form = MultipleFileExampleForm() # A empty, unbound form

    documents = Document.objects.all

    return render_to_response(
        'example_form.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from here? A ModelForm save method does have a commit kwarg, but a Model save method does not. Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: @DanielRoseman don't you wish Stack Overflow required a traceback whenever a question was asked with a phrase about "getting an error"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean by traceback? ive also updated post with models.py and forms.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman nvm i added traceback in screen shot image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not sub classing **django.forms.ModelForm**, yet, you are writing your code like you are.

You need to subclass ModelForm (which has the save method with the commit argument).

Calling super will not work either, as the super class has no save method with that argument.

Remove the **commit=False** it will never work unless you rewrite your code to subclass **django.forms.ModelForm**

In any case the save method should always return an instance. I suggest you rename your method to **save_all_files** or something similar. You will not be able to use **commit=False** to save multiple object in your save method. It is not the intended use.

For further reading, you can read the source to know how the **commit=False** works in the **ModelForm class** at the following address :

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are completely overriding the save method, which gets rid of the existing functionality (i.e. the commit arg). Try running a `super()` at the end so that it has the existing save functionality as well.

```
def save(self):
    for f in self.cleaned_data['input_file']:
        Document.objects.create(
            input_file=f
        )
    super(MultipleFileExampleForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Still won't work, because the subclassed method doesn't accept args and kwargs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I actually just had this bug and figured out it was because I was overriding the save method without the commit param. For a form overriding forms.ModelForm, save signature should be `def save(self, commit=True):`