# save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Tags: django, django-views

I am implementing a feature that allows a user to upload images to their blog. When the user uploads a single image I get the error `'PostImages' object is not iterable` and when a user uploads multiple images I get the error `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'` this is the one I am currently trying to fix

view

```
def DetailPostView(request, pk):
model = Post
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

formImages = PostImagesForm

if request.method == 'POST':
    formImages = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
    if formImages.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            formImages = formImages.save(commit=False)
            formImages.post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
            formImages.save()
    else:
        print(formImages.errors)
        

context = {
    'post':post, 'formImages':formImages,
    }
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

form

```
class PostImagesForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = PostImages
    fields = ('images',)
    widgets = {
        'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
    }
```

I found this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131198/save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-commit-django-error) that was also dealing with the same error but I dont really understand it. I have done the same thing on all my other forms without issue.

Comment: `formImages = formImages.save(commit=False)` makes no sense, since you here assign the instance wrapped in the form to `formImages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redeclaring formImages and this might be the error. Your `formImages = formImages.save(commit=False)` can't be saved with this. If you call formImages.save() you're calling `formImages.save(commit=False).save()`...

Try to replace`formImages = formImages.save(commit=False)`
with `formImages.save(commit=False)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When i replace it with your suggestion i get the error ``null value in column "post_id" of relation "blog_postimages" violates not-null constraint`` and the form does not submit anything